# How do you handle error handling and commits in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgres 13.5 and I am unsure how to combine commit and error handling in a stored procedure or DO block. I know that if I include the EXCEPTION clause in my block, then I cannot include a commit.

I am new to Postgres.  It has also been over 15 years since I have written SQL that was working with transactions. When I was working with transactions I was using Oracle and recall using AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION to resolve some of these issues. I am just not sure how to do something like that in Postgres.

Here is a very simplified DO block. As I said above, I know that the Commits will cause the procedure to throw and exception. But, if I remove the EXCEPTION clause, then how will I trap an error if it happens? After reading many things, I still have not found a solution. So, I am not understanding something that will lead me to the solution.

```
Do
$$
DECLARE
    v_Start timestamptz;
    v_id integer;
    v_message_type varchar(500);

Begin
    select current_timestamp into start;

    select q.id, q.message_type into (v_id, v_message_type) from message_queue;

    call Load_data(v_id, v_message_type);
    commit; -- if Load_Data completes successfully, I want to commmit the data

    insert into log (id, message_type, Status, start, end)
    values (v_id, v_message_type, 'Success', v_start, Currrent_Timestamp);
    commit; -- commit the log issert for success
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN others THEN
      insert into log (id, message_type, status, start, end, error_message)
      values (v_id, v_message_type, 'Failue', v_start, Currrent_Timestamp, SQLERRM || '', ' || 
      SQLSTATE );
      commit; -- commit the log insert for failure. 

end;
$$
```

Thanks!
Since this is a pattern that I will have to do tens of times, I want to understand the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot use transaction management statements in a subtransaction, you will have to move part of the processing to the client side.

But your sample code doesn't need any transaction management at all! Simply remove all the `COMMIT` statements, and the procedure will work just as you want it to. Remember that PostgreSQL uses the autocommit mode, so your procedure call from the client will automatically run in its own transaction and commit when it is done.

But perhaps your sample code is simplified, and you would like more complicated processing (looping etc.) in your actual use cases. So let's discuss your options:

One option is to remove the `EXCEPTION` handler and move only that part to the client side: if the procedure causes an error, roll back and insert a log message. Another, perhaps cleaner, method is to move the whole transaction management to the client side. In that case, you would replace the complete procedure with client code and call `load_data` directly from client code.

Comment: +1 @LaurenzAlbe, Thanks for answering my question. I was hoping that there was a way to encapsulate the whole solution in the database, similar to using packages in Oracle. But, I will move the error handling to the client side. Thanks Again.